# Does $|x| \leq |y|$ imply $|\mathsf E[x]| \leq |\mathsf E[y]|$?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Does $|x| \leq |y|$ imply $|\mathsf{E}[x]| \leq |\mathsf{E}[y]|$?

Comment: Say $Y$ is $\pm 1 $ with equal chance, and $X$ is the constant $\frac 12$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is actually one counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

No, $|x| \leq |y|$ doesn't necessarily imply $|\mathsf E[x]| \leq |\mathsf{E}[y]|$.

One counterexample is as follow:

- $x$: $\mathsf P\{x=-1\} = \frac13$, $\mathsf P\{x=+1\} = \frac23$;
- $y$: $\mathsf P\{y=-2\} = \frac12$, $\mathsf P\{y=+2\} = \frac12$.

$\mathsf{E}[x] = (-1) \cdot \mathsf P\{x=-1\} + (+1) \cdot \mathsf P\{x=+1\} = -\frac13+\frac23 = \frac13$

$\mathsf{E}[y] = (-2) \cdot \mathsf P\{y=-2\} + (+2) \cdot \mathsf P\{y=+2\} = -1+1 = 0$

In this case, $1=|x|< |y|=2$, yet $\frac13 = |\mathsf{E}[x]| > |\mathsf{E}[y]| =0$.