# Does $|\mathsf{E}(xy)|\leq |\mathsf{E}(x)| \cdot |\mathsf{E}(y)|$ hold?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Does $|\mathsf{E}(xy)|\leq |\mathsf{E}(x)| \cdot |\mathsf{E}(y)|$ hold for any random variable $x$, $y$? Here $\mathsf{E}$ is the expectation.

Comment: Please edit your post to include your efforts.  As with [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4848714/does-x-leq-y-imply-mathsf-ex-leq-mathsf-ey?noredirect=1#comment10330660_4848714), it should be easy for you to construct a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks for your kind remind. Since this inequality is not obvious for me, as suggested, one counterexample is included.

Comment: Simpler counterexample:  $X=Y$ and $E[X]=0=E[Y]$ (and $X$ is not constant).

Answer (score 2):

No, $|\mathsf{E}(xy)|\leq |\mathsf{E}(x)| \cdot |\mathsf{E}(y)|$ does not hold for any random variable $x$, $y$.

Assume that $x$, $y$ are independent r.v., it holds that $|\mathsf{E}(xy)| = |\mathsf{E}(x)\cdot \mathsf{E}(y)| \leq |\mathsf{E}(x)| \cdot |\mathsf{E}(y)|$.

However, one counter example for the dependent random variables $x,y$ can be given as follows

- $x$: $\mathsf P\{x=-1\} = \frac12$, $\mathsf P\{x=+1\} = \frac12$;
- $y$: $y = \begin{cases}+1 &\text{if}\ x>0 \\ -1 &\text{if}\ x<0 \end{cases}$

Then
\begin{align*}
\mathsf E (xy) &=(+1) \cdot \mathsf P (xy=+1) + (-1)\cdot \mathsf P (xy=-1)\\
& = (+1) \cdot \left(\mathsf P (x=-1, y=-1) + \mathsf P (x=+1, y=+1) \right)\\
& = (+1) \cdot \left(\mathsf P (x=-1) \mathsf P(y=-1| x=-1) + \mathsf P (x=+1)\cdot \mathsf P(y=+1| x=+1) \right)\\
& = (+1) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 + \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1\right)\\
& = +1
\end{align*}
where it is impossible for $xy=-1$ (i.e., $\mathsf P(xy=-1)= 0$).

$\mathsf E(x) = 1\cdot 1/2 -1 \cdot 1/2 = 0$. Thus, $1 = |\mathsf{E}(xy)| > |\mathsf{E}(x)| \cdot |\mathsf{E}(y)| = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

simple counterexample here: 
if
$$E(X) = E(Y) = 0$$
then
$$Cov(X, Y) = E[(X - E(X))(Y - E(Y))] = E(XY)$$
if
$$|E(XY)| \le |E(X)||E(Y)|$$
holds, which means $Cov(X, Y) = 0$
but $Cov(X, Y) > 0$ is possible if $E(X) = E(Y) = 0$